# How to apply style to multiple classes on hover of an element?

Tags: javascript, css

Whenever I hover over `#Rock div` I want it to apply a style to both `.RockToScissors` & `.RockToLizard` at the same. A the moment I have:

```html
<div onmouseover="overRock()" onmouseout="outRock()">
    <svg>
        <path stroke="#000" fill="#000"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Then in Javascript I have:

```js
function overRock() {
    var myPara = document.querySelector(".RockToScissors");
    myPara.style.stroke = "#008000";
    myPara.style.fill = "#008000";
}

function outRock() {
    var myPara = document.querySelector(".RockToScissors");
    myPara.style.stroke = "#000";
    myPara.style.fill = "#000";
}
```

But this only allows me to apply the styling to one class. How can I make it apply to both `.RockToScissors` & `.RockToLizard` at the same time when hovering `#Rock div`?

I've tried `var myPara = document.querySelectorAll(".RockToScissors, .RockToLizard");` but then the  style doesn't apply to either.

Comment: is .RockToScissors & .RockToLizard children of #Rock div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include both the class as part of the selector in `querySelectorAll()`. Then loop through them to set the style individually:

Try the following way:

```
function overRock() {
  var myPara = document.querySelectorAll(".RockToScissors, .RockToLizard");
  myPara.forEach(function(el){
    el.style.stroke = "#008000";
    el.style.fill = "#008000";
  });
}

function outRock() {
  var myPara = .querySelectorAll(".RockToScissors, .RockToLizard");
  myPara.forEach(function(el){
    el.style.stroke = "#000";
    el.style.fill = "#000";
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `document.querySelectorAll(".RockToScissors, .RockToLizard");` to target both elements.

`document.querySelectorAll()` supports all CSS selectors, and `,` is [also valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping).

Comment: I tried that but then the style doesn't apply to either of them.

Comment: You then have to iterate through what `document.querySelectorAll()` returns. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57019129/6401290)!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using css -

If the .RockToScissors and .RockToLizard is directly inside the container:

```
#Rock div:hover > .RockToScissors, #Rock div:hover > .RockToLizard { //css to modify }
```

If .RockToScissors and .RockToLizard is next to (after containers closing tag) the container:

```
#Rock div:hover + .RockToScissors, #Rock div:hover + .RockToLizard { //css to modify }
```

If the .RockToScissors and .RockToLizard is somewhere inside the container:

```
#Rock div:hover .RockToScissors, #Rock div:hover .RockToLizard { //css to modify }
```

If the .RockToScissors and .RockToLizard is a sibling of the container:

```
#Rock div:hover ~ .RockToScissors, #Rock div:hover ~ .RockToLizard { //css to modify }
```

Comment: ^This is why I didn't do CSS because they aren't inside, next to or sibling of each other. That's why I was using JS. Luckily someone has shown me how to do it with QuerySelectorAll.